# Seaborn plot display out of order in ipython cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, seaborn

When I run the below code, I would expect to see the Seaborn figure and then the text from the print statement underneath it, but instead it is on top.

```py
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.relplot(x = "total_bill", y = "tip", data = tips);

print('this should be at the bottom')
```

How can I have the print statement display underneath the Seaborn figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution appears to work in my Jupyter Notebook when combined with `plt.show()` from `matplotlib`. Now the plot will be displayed first before the `print` statement gets executed.

As put simply by [@ImportanceOfBeingEarnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) below, in the absence of `plt.show()` in your cell containing the plot command, the plots will be shown at the end of the cell.

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
plt.show()
print('this should be at the bottom')
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "trick". It's simply that if you don't have plt.show anywhere in your cell, plots are shown when reaching the end of the cell and the end of the cell comes after any print statement inside of it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Point taken. I added your comment to my answer. Thanks!